# Certain Facebook insights tables do not return data after 1/25? (Both FQL and Graph API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I've done everything to try and figure out why this is happening. It has nothing to do with deprecated insights; it's tables like page_fans which should be returning data. The data returns empty for every day after 1/25 until now. I read somewhere this is a Facebook bug but it's been like two weeks. Is there any hope in sight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the #1 bug currently on Facebook's bug site: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164619063648278

Facebook is notorious for taking forever to fix bugs, if they ever even get fixed. Not much you can do until then.